# How to convert inline SVG on the server?

Tags: c#, css, svg, raphael, background-image

I need to set the resulting inline SVG as a `background-image` on some other element as shown [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CT3Za/). As this works only in Chrome I need some other way to set the client drawn SVG as `background-image`.

Another, maybe simpler inline SVG, is the RaphaelJS demo as [seen here](http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html).

```
<svg height="480" version="1.1" width="640" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: -0.90625px;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="640" height="480" r="10" rx="10" ry="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect><circle cx="320" cy="240" r="60" fill="#223fa3" stroke="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 0.5;" stroke-width="80" stroke-opacity="0.5"></circle></svg>
```

Is it possible to convert inline SVG (created by RaphaelJS on the client) on the server to  a "real" SVG file? It's a Windows (.NET/c#) server environment on which the conversion should take place.

**Edit**

As Robert Longson noticed I was missing the `charset=` and additionally it looks like I used the wrong function (`encodeURI`) to encode the inline SVG.

Just for the sake of completeness here the code fragment for setting the `background-image` that works for me

```
var svgUrl = 'url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent($('#raphaelPaper').html()) + '")';
$('#pictureDummy').css('background-image', svgUrl);
```

Comment: Why don't you simple get the content of the ```<svg>``` node and save it in a ```.svg``` file on the server side ?

Comment: @Blackhole It looks like the inline `<svg>` is not the same as `.svg` file content. I tried already to save it, but neither Inkskape nor any browser can open the file. I'm not deep inside the SVG stuff, but it looks like just saving isn't enough.

Comment: I just found a library called `Raphael.Export`. Looks like it can export the client side generated SVG to a .svg file. But not sure if it works with my generated thing. Just trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works in Chrome because your data URL is [invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format). It should start like this...

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg
```

You're missing the `charset=` part. You might consider reporting that as a [blink bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry?template=Defect%20on%20Windows&comment=Chrome%20Version%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3a%20%3CCopy%20from%3a%20%27about%3aversion%27%3E%0AOS%20Version%3a%206.1%20%28Windows%207,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%29%0AURLs%20%28if%20applicable%29%20%3a%0AOther%20browsers%20tested%3a%0A%20%20Add%20OK%20or%20FAIL%20after%20other%20browsers%20where%20you%20have%20tested%20this%20issue%3a%0A%20%20%20%20%20Safari%205%3a%0A%20%20Firefox%204.x%3a%0A%20%20%20%20%20IE%207/8/9%3a%0A%0AWhat%20steps%20will%20reproduce%20the%20problem?%0A1.%0A2.%0A3.%0A%0AWhat%20is%20the%20expected%20result?%0A%0A%0AWhat%20happens%20instead%20of%20that?%0A%0A%0APlease%20provide%20any%20additional%20information%20below.%20Attach%20a%20screenshot%20if%0Apossible.%0A%0A).

Here's a [corrected version](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/JbFV7/)

Comment: Looks like your hint generally solved my issue. But I have an issue with generated SVG on IE, though. Your corrected version works fine on IE. But If I dynamically create the SVG on IE it doesn't work by setting the backround-image anymore. 

Take a look at the jsfiddle at the end of the comment for a not working IE version. It works for the rest of browsers I tested with. 

The resulting SVG in IE is quite different to the SVG that I used for my initial question and your corrected version. Any idea what the issue might be with IE? 

http://jsfiddle.net/tBc3g/

Comment: Feel free to ask another question. It's difficult to ask and answer in comments.

Comment: I created a follow up question on this. Would be awesome if could have a look. I'm not able to find out what's going wrong for IE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269613/inline-svg-not-working-as-background-image-in-ie